# system.io.ioexception the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process in c# using as an email attachment

Tags: c#, exception, crystal-reports, email-attachments

I am attaching a pdf file exported from crystal report. When I use this on development PC it works fine. However when I try on clients PC it gives me an exception

> system.io.ioexception the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Here's my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {         
            printbanqoute.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, "G:\\" + filename);////For Client PC

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        MailMessage mm = new MailMessage();
        try
        {   
            string toemail = BLDashboard.email;
            string custnm = BLDashboard.custname;

            mm.From = new MailAddress("operations@kaem.in", "Kashif Ahhmed");
            mm.To.Add(new MailAddress(toemail, custnm));
            mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
            string name = BLDashboard.custname;

            mm.Subject = "Qoutation ";

            String Body = "<div>Hello " + name + ",<br> Thank you for considering us for your next Party/Event, here is the qoute for the Party/Event.<br> If any queries you can reach us at 6096464445. <br> Thank You</div>";
            mm.Body = Body;

            mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("G:\\" + filename));///For Cleint PC

            SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient("smtp.kaem.in");
            sc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("operations@kaem.in", "******");
            sc.Send(mm);

            MessageBox.Show("Email successfully sent to " + toemail);
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to send email due to following error:\n\n" + e1.Message, "Email send error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            mm.Dispose();//// Later Added this line 
        }

    }
```

After searching I added

```
 finally
        {
            mm.Dispose();//// Later Added this line 
        }
```

Now it just gave me error no exception.
I tried Disabling and trying, but same issue.

Here's the exception that I am getting:

[image: IOException]

Comment: Did you try to clean all pdf files from task manager before running the system?

Comment: i dont see any pdf file(s) in task manager, also drive I am accessing is a External HDD

Comment: Could you highlight the line in which the exception gets thrown? It's probably the line in which the mail message gets initialized? Then it's possible that you have another message being handled? Did you try rebooting already?